# How to add an icon inside an <a> element using only CSS

Tags: html, css

I have created this header for a wizard:

Js Fiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/7bduw43j/

HTML Code:

```
<ul id="wizHeader">
<li>
<a href="#" class="currentStep">Step 1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="nextStep">Step 2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="nextStep">Step 3</a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
 #wizHeader li .prevStep
{
    background-color: #669966 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .prevStep:after
{
    border-left-color:#669966 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .currentStep
{
    background-color: #3B96B6 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .currentStep:after
{
    border-left-color: #3B96B6 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .nextStep
{
    background-color:#C2C2C2 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .nextStep:after
{
    border-left-color:#C2C2C2 !important;
}
#wizHeader
{
    list-style: none !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    font: 15px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
#wizHeader li
{
    float: left !important;
}
#wizHeader li a
{
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 55px !important;
    background: brown !important; /* fallback color */
    background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1) !important;
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
    float: left !important;
}
#wizHeader li a:after
{
    content: " " !important;
    display: block !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent !important; /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1) !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    margin-top: -50px !important;
    left: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
#wizHeader li a:before
{
    content: " " !important;
    display: block !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 30px solid white !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    margin-top: -50px !important;
    margin-left: 1px !important;
    left: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1;
}        
#wizHeader li:first-child a
{
    padding-left: 10px !important;
}
#wizHeader li:last-child 
{
    padding-right: 50px !important;
}
#wizHeader li a:hover
{
    background: #FFC13C !important;
}
#wizHeader li a:hover:after
{
    border-left-color: #FFC13C !important;
}
```

The effect I would like to achieve is something like this:
[Telerik Wizard Example](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip/examples/application-scenarios/wizard/defaultcs.aspx)
Where each step has a small number icon next to it.
How will I achieve this using only css?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Move the pseudo elements to the `li` and then you can use a separate pseudo element on the `anchor`. Or add a span inside the link.

Comment: Try adding  a background to the a by making a display : inline-block, and give the background no repeat and set the background to the position with  help of background-position-x and background-position-y

Answer (score 1):

You can make similar that using CSS. **[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/7bduw43j/5/)**

Just add numbers insite `<li>`  `<span class="no">1</span>` and apply style using 'no' class name.

Try below code.

```
<ul id="wizHeader">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="currentStep"><span class="no">1</span> Step 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="nextStep"><span class="no">2</span> Step 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#" class="nextStep"><span class="no">3</span> Step 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#wizHeader li .prevStep
{
    background-color: #669966 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .prevStep:after
{
    border-left-color:#669966 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .currentStep
{
    background-color: #3B96B6 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .currentStep:after
{
    border-left-color: #3B96B6 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .nextStep
{
    background-color:#C2C2C2 !important;
}
#wizHeader li .nextStep:after
{
    border-left-color:#C2C2C2 !important;
}
#wizHeader
{
    list-style: none !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    font: 15px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
#wizHeader li
{
    float: left !important;
}
#wizHeader li a
{
    color: white !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 38px !important;
    background: brown !important; /* fallback color */
    background: hsla(34,85%,35%,1) !important;
    position: relative !important;
    display: block !important;
    float: left !important;
}
#wizHeader li a:after
{
    content: " " !important;
    display: block !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent !important; /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 30px solid hsla(34,85%,35%,1) !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    margin-top: -50px !important;
    left: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1 !important;
}
#wizHeader li a:before
{
    content: " " !important;
    display: block !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent !important;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent !important;
    border-left: 30px solid white !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    margin-top: -50px !important;
    margin-left: 1px !important;
    left: 100% !important;
    z-index: 1;
}        
#wizHeader li:first-child a
{
    padding-left: 10px !important;
}
#wizHeader li:last-child 
{
    padding-right: 50px !important;
}
#wizHeader li a:hover
{
    background: #FFC13C !important;
}
#wizHeader li a:hover:after
{
    border-left-color: #FFC13C !important;
}
.no{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple ... Below code might help you

```
<li>
   <a href="#" class="currentStep">
      <span>
         <span><img src="path/to/img"></span>
         <span>Step 1</span>
      <span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Repeat above for each `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Please clean your code like this the add your ion in the anchor

```css
#wizHeader
{
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    font: 15px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#wizHeader li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #C2C2C2;
}

#wizHeader li a
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 55px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#wizHeader li:after
{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent; /* Go big on the size, and let overflow hide */
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid #C2C2C2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
#wizHeader li:before
{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    left: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}        
#wizHeader li:first-child a
{
    padding-left: 10px
}
#wizHeader li:last-child 
{
    padding-right: 50px
}

#wizHeader li.prevStep
{
    background-color: #669966
}
#wizHeader li.prevStep:after
{
    border-left-color:#669966
}
#wizHeader li.currentStep
{
    background-color: #3B96B6
}
#wizHeader li.currentStep:after
{
    border-left-color: #3B96B6 
}
#wizHeader li.nextStep
{
    background-color:#C2C2C2
}
#wizHeader li.nextStep:after
{
    border-left-color:#C2C2C2
}

#wizHeader li:hover
{
    background: #FFC13C
}
#wizHeader li:hover:after
{
    border-left-color: #FFC13C
}
```

```html
<ul id="wizHeader">
 <li class="currentStep">
 <a href="#">&reg; Step 1</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nextStep">
 <a href="#">&copy; Step 2</a>
 </li>
 <li class="nextStep">
 <a href="#">&Theta; Step 3</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :before or :after pseudoclasses and their property content.
The nature of content: can be used as counter:

```
<h3>Introduction</h3>
<h3>Body</h3>
<h3>Conclusion</h3>
```

And CSS:

```
h3:before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: "Section" counter(section) ": ";
}
```

The first string is "Section". Than counter which will count h3 tags and than ": " is what will come after the iteration number.

Output:

> ```
> Section1: Introduction
> Section2: Body
> Section3: Conclusion
> ```

You can also have nested sections (ex. 1.2 1.3 etc)
Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters